# Apply Shift Operation on Pandas Dataframe based on Filter Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe which sort of looks like below image. For a particular C-ID, if there is a value present in the year columns for Sub-ID =0, Then that value should be used. If it is blank, then Sum of value in year columns of Sub-ID's 1, 2 and 3 should be calculated and Sub-ID = 0 field should be updated.

I think the Pandas shift() function should be used, but cant get around the filter condition which must be used.

There is always a chance all fields for a particular C-ID is blank. **I cannot use a group by** because if Sub-ID =0 already has a value, it might not be sum of the Sub-ID's 1,2 and 3 and should not be calculated again.

[image]

The result should look like this :

[image]

Data in text format for original table:

```
|C-ID|Sub-ID|UID|2018|2019|2020|

|1|0|1|21||30|
|1|1|1.1|15|20||
|1|2|1.2|4|8||
|1|3|1.2|2|11||
|2|0|2|32||25|
|2|1|2.1|21|30|15|
|2|2|2.2|4|12|5|
|2|3|2.3|5|13|5|
|3|0|3||40||
|3|1|3.1|20||12|
|3|2|3.2|10||10|
|3|3|3.3|5||17|
```

Can someone help?

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you've written so far, even if it does not yet produce the desired result.

Comment: An easier approach might be to clear the Sub-ID 0 values if there is something present in that column of Sub-ID 1.  Once you do that, you have a simple `groupby` and `sum` operation.

Comment: And provide all the data in a reproducible format (as code)

Comment: `df.loc[df['Sub-ID'].between(1,3)].groupby('CID')[[2018,2019,2020]].sum().assign(**{'Sub-ID': 0})`